# How do i insert new record in this table?

Tags: sql, insert

I'm sorry for this noob question.

[There're 2 tables](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question599.htm): the smaller one is derived from bigger one.
How do i insert new record into bigger table??

```
INSERT INTO people (lname, fname, city, age, salary) VALUES (' Doe','John','Paris', '25','1000$' );
```

but bigger table contains city as number. How should i insert 'Paris'?? Should i know its number beforehand?? But 'Paris' isn't in Cities (smaller) table!!
How do records get inserted in bigger (people) table??

Comment: Nice nick! You have to do 2 inserts, one for city and then one on people, like rabudde said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Added `IF` block to check for Paris.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM City WHERE City = 'Paris')
Insert INTO City (City) VALUES ('Paris')

DECLARE @Cid int = (SELECT CityID FROM City WHERE City = 'Paris')

INSERT INTO people (lname, fname, city, age, salary) 
VALUES (' Doe','John', @cid, '25','1000$' )
```

I made an assumption about the structure of the `city` table obviously.

You could also parameterize this with a `@city` variable and sub that for `'Paris'` everywhere in the code.

Comment: What does 'select 1' mean?? why 1??

Comment: @JNK in case of existing entry in table `city` it's inefficient to doing a SELECT twice

Comment: @DrStrangelove - You are only checking to see if a record exists.  `SELECT 1` is so the query doesn't pull any actual data from the table.  All you want to know is if there is a record for Paris.

Comment: see my answer: doing INSERT only if SELECT returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
adopted solution for existing entries in city table. as I wrote in comments, transactions could be ommited (for example when running as stored procedure)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @city_id INT
        SELECT @city_id=id FROM city WHERE name='Paris'
        IF @city_id IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO city (name) VALUES ('Paris')
            SET @city_id=@@IDENTITY
        END
        INSERT INTO people (lname, fname, city, age, salary) VALUES ('Doe','John',@city_id, '25','1000$' );
END TRANSACTION
```

Comment: @drstrangelove take a look at my answer

Comment: -1 - Getting last auto-increment is a bad practice for this.  If there are concurrent inserts you will use the wrong ID

Comment: in this case, i know 'Paris' isn't in city table. but what if city table contained many cities, how would i know if 'Paris' in it? What will my SQL look like then??

Comment: it depends on it, if you want to do it from PHP or in a stored procedure, you should first have a look into city table (SELECT) if you get no result, then you have to INSERT city first

Comment: @Drstrangelove - I updated my answer for that condition for you

Comment: @rabudde - then clarify your answer.  As it stands it's a bad practice.  You don't mention transactions at all.

Comment: @JNK is it bad practise because you think so? Refs? Have a look at MySQL and MSSQL documentation and you can see, what they states. MySQL: "Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.", MSSQL: "@@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session". So they both don't talk about transactions.

Comment: @@Identity is not always reliable.

Comment: May want to add a `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT @city_id=id FROM city`  since it will throw an error as written.  Otherwise good answer, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In the insert to the people table, the value of the city column should be the number of the city you want the person to be linked to - so in your quoted example replace 'Paris' with the city number for Paris.

If you want to create a new person record with a city that does not yet exist in the cities table, you'll need to do an insert into the cities table first, get the number of the created city and then use that in your insert to the people table.